# React native TextInput ref error, focus is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to programatically focus `TextInput` element with a certain delay after it has mounted, I've got following component (a view that shows input and button)

For some reason this gets error saying

> _this2.inputRef.focus is not a function

I'm not sure why. One out of place thing is that I get flow saying that `createRef()` doesn't exist on `React`, but I am assuming this is just missing flow definition now, as I am using `react 16.3.1` and this was added in 16.3, plus there is no error when its called.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import Button from '../../composites/Button'
import TextInput from '../../composites/TextInput'
import OnboardingStore from '../../store/OnboardingStore'
import withStore from '../../store'
import { durationNormal } from '../../services/Animation'

/**
 * Types
 */
export type Props = {
  OnboardingStore: OnboardingStore
}

/**
 * Component
 */
class CharacterNameView extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.inputRef.focus(), durationNormal)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.keyboardTimeout)
  }

  keyboardTimeout: TimeoutID
  inputRef = React.createRef()

  render() {
    const { OnboardingStore } = this.props
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TextInput
          ref={this.inputRef}
          enablesReturnKeyAutomatically
          value={OnboardingStore.state.username}
          onChangeText={username => OnboardingStore.mutationUsername(username)}
          placeholder="Username"
          blurOnSubmit
          returnKeyType="done"
          onSubmitEditing={/* TODO */ () => null}
        />
        <Button disabled={!OnboardingStore.state.username} color="GREEN" onPress={() => null}>
          Create
        </Button>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default withStore(OnboardingStore)(CharacterNameView)
```

TextInput component I use is imported from this file

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, TextInput as Input } from 'react-native'
import RatioBgImage from '../components/RatioBgImage'
import { deviceWidth } from '../services/Device'

/**
 * Types
 */
export type Props = {
  style?: any
}

/**
 * Component
 */
class TextInput extends Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = {
    style: null
  }

  render() {
    const { style, ...props } = this.props
    return (
      <RatioBgImage source={{ uri: 'input_background' }} width={70} ratio={0.1659}>
        <Input
          {...props}
          placeholderTextColor="#4f4a38"
          selectionColor="#797155"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          keyboardAppearance="dark"
          style={[styles.input, style]}
        />
      </RatioBgImage>
    )
  }
}

export default TextInput

/**
 * Styles
 */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    width: '96.4%',
    height: '97.45%',
    color: '#797155',
    fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.043,
    marginLeft: '1%',
    paddingLeft: '5%'
  }
})
```

Below is what `this.innerRef` looks like, I don't see any focus property on it at the moment

[image]

Comment: try `this.inputRef.current.focus()`

Comment: or find the node handle for the `TextInput` using `React.findNodeHandle` by passing in the ref for the `TextInput`

Comment: Does old version of functional ref works?

Comment: I also noticed that your `TextInput` is imported from a different file. Can you post that code too please.

Comment: @bennygenel completely forgot about this part, I added it to the question, however its passing all props like ref to react-native input

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I can access current, but there is no `focus` function on it either :/

Comment: @Ilja can you try [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component) please.

Comment: Any luck with @bennygenel approach? If not can you create a fiddle with an example?

Answer (score 1):

`inputRef` is a property of the class instance, set it inside a class method.

Using a constructor, for instance:

```
class CharacterNameView extends Component<Props> {
  constructor() {
    this.inputRef = React.createRef()
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is an issue, my syntax works as part of es6/7, it defines the ref correctly, but there is no focus on it

Answer (score 0):

My issue was in using `React.createRef()` and assuming I am setting it on a child component. Unfortunately I missed part of the docs about [React.forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) That I had to use in a child component so ref gets set properly.